# VMWare ESX/ESXi CPU usage

Tags: c++, vmware, gsoap, vmware-sdk

I'm using Visual studio 2010 and (native) C++ trying to extract the overall CPU usage of the VMWare host and then the CPU usage of each running VM.

I've looked into VMWare Webservice SDK 4.1 using gSoap to build a C++ interface, but its to slow and to cluncky to be a realistic alternative (resulting cpp files take 4 hours to compile and end up as a 70 MB binary, that would be ok, if not a single call would take *minutes* to execute).

Do anyone have a tips on an alternative solution/sdk ?

Comment: seen this? http://communities.vmware.com/thread/223151

Comment: Are you tied to using C++ alone for this? If you can use Perl then i can give some help

Answer (score 3):

I assume you've gone over all known VMware APIs, so how about this different approach... Simply SSH into the ESX machine and execute some command line utilities to get the information you need. To get all the information you may ever need, you can execute `esxtop -b -n1`.

To connect using SSH, you can use [plink.exe](http://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/putty/) that allows you to execute stuff from the command line, much like `ssh` on Linux machines. You can also use one of the many available SSH libraries, such as [libssh](http://www.libssh.org/).

Answer (score 1):

How important is it to use a VMWare specific solution?  Besides using a webservice or VIX which just wrap calls to a soap server for ESX, maybe you're overlooking the simplest solution here.  Gathering and monitoring details about the performance of any host is best done with snmp or so I'd like to believe.  Its simple; it does what you're asking for and you don't have to deal with the overhead of the SDK.

If you decide to use an SNMP solution, I recommend net-snmp.

Comment: IF it where an option I would use SNMP, but VMWare have no support anymore for SNMP, ESX is legacy software and ESXi lacks offical support for SNMP.

Comment: Hmmm.  I could have sworn that ESX had support for it.  The last time we deployed ESX servers, Net-SNMP came built in.